# awk sub/gsub a substring between 2 matches with end-delimiter repeated

Tags: awk, substring, gsub, substitution

I've a string (`file`) :

```sh
2   61009818    .   TAGG    T   .   .   ad_alt=9;ad_ref=48;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;
```

how can i replace the substring `ad_ref=48` with `example=something`, in order to obtain:

```sh
2   61009818    .   TAGG    T   .   .   ad_alt=9;example=something;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;
```

with `awk` substitution?

I tried :

```sh
awk  '{ sub(/(ad_ref=.*\;)/,"example=something")} 1' file
```

but it replaces all, since first match until end-of-line:

```sh
# output
2   61009818    .   TAGG    T   .   .   ad_alt=9;example=something
```

While I need to replace chars only until first `;`.
I found different posts but all are based on unique end-delimiter, how tell the command to substitute ONLY the part between start-delimiter and FIRST-end-delimiter (`;` in my case) ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `ad_ref=[^;]*` or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub(/ad_ref=[^;]*/,"example=something")} 1' file
2   61009818    .   TAGG    T   .   .   ad_alt=9;example=something;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;

$ sed 's/ad_ref=[^;]*/example=something/' file
2   61009818    .   TAGG    T   .   .   ad_alt=9;example=something;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;
```